# How to detect wemux user who executing the command

Tags: tmux

Let's say `root` user has created wemux session. Linux user `alice` and `bob` joins this session as pair.

If user `alice` types the `whoami` command, shell will be shown `root` as the user

```
$ whoami
root
```

Is there a way to detect who is executing command or script.

For example, if `alice` runs the following shell script in wemux session started by `root`, the user variable should be populated with `alice` value.

```
#!/bin/bash

user = # code to detect user
```